# Does Ace Editor work with the language C for compiling code?

Tags: c, ace-editor

I have been working on a tutorial website for C and I wanted to use Ace to be my editor. When I tried looking for the language C in the mode folder all I saw was c_cpp.js and c9search.js. Nothing of regular C showed up. Is there anything I am missing here or does Ace just not support C at all? Side note: I did see a c.snippets but that was the closest I can get. Any help would be great!

Comment: I suspect `c_cpp.js` is for both C and C++.

Comment: Ace is an editor, not a compiler.

Comment: If you are leaning C, learn to compile your programs from the command line. That way you learn what options are needed to compile your code. After you know how you want your code compiled, then you can teach an IDE how you want the compiler invoked, and check whether your editor can do the same.

Comment: Did you try "c_cpp.js"? If so, why do you think it is not what you expect? Please [edit] your question if you have new information.

Comment: c_cpp is the mode for C and C++